# addressing an array with a "string integer" as a key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've used the json_decode function to convert the given json into an object, I can then address each of these by using something like $givenobject->name or $givenobject->productdetails->name. the problem is, instead of using a simple index for a key, the table I am trying to decode from has used an integer for the key that's being treated as a string. I cant do $givenobject->productdetails->"1"->name since that would just throw an error.

Heres an example of the given json:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "info":{
    "1":{
      "name":"Example",
      "description":"Example description"
    }
  }
}
```

How would I extract the "name" variable from this table without having to go:

$tabledata->info->***1***->name

Comment: Decode it as an array -> see second parameter in `json_decode()`

Comment: is this fragment shown above actual and there's no other nested structures with key `name`?

Comment: But to answer the object question: `echo $givenobject->info->{1}->name;` Or `{'1'}` will work as well.

Comment: $array = json_decode($json, true);
$name = $array['info'][1]['name'];
echo $name;